# Mobile design animate or not?

Tags: website-design

Currently I have a website that uses animations like fade in/out and slide up/down.

On a PC it looks smooth but on a phone it looks like the FPS can't keep up, somewhat rough

I've looked at some of the popular websites and not many use animations.

Is it better to just not use animations at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should keep animation to its minimum when access via mobile due to bandwidth, viewport and JavaScript (rendering power) limitation. There are tons of articles written on Mobile best practices, do a search.

Having said that, you might want to [use CSS to do the animation](https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation). CSS animation has JavaScript equivalent of fade in/out and other slick animating properties. If you still want to stick to JS, then you should check out [GreenSock](http://greensock.com/gsap).

Answer (score 1):

**Make them slick or remove them completely.**

---

Animations are generally there to add subtle improvements to the experience rather than to add functionality, so if they're affecting the experience by looking rough then they defeat their point. Make them slick (improve their performance, use CSS animations, etc) or remove them completely.